# How can I detect if the user just wanted to scroll, and not tap on an UIImageView inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've implemented an UIScrollView which contains a grid of UIImageView objects. For both, the superview and it's subviews, userInteractionEnabled is YES. As the user scrolls and his/her finger touches an UIImageView, it imediately recognizes a tap on that, which is not what I want ;)

Inside of that UIImageView objects I have this method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == self && [touch tapCount] >= 1) {
        NSLog(@"Cooooool! The user touched me!");
    }
}
```

Is there a way how I could recognize something like "oh no, the user actually wanted to scroll only, so don't take that touch too serious!"? Basically, what I need is the behavior of the home screen, where a finger may touch an icon, but when the user starts scrolling and lifts the finger off, the touched app will not be launched.

Answer (score 2):

`UIScrollView` has already implemented that behavior for you. If the user is quick enough to drag, your `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method will simply never be called.

If, on the other hand, the user is slow and the scroll view forwards the touch to your `UIImageView` subclass, but then only realizes the user meant to scroll, it will call your custom class' `-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method.

Just implement it, and you'll be notified of cancelled touches.